# Testing a trait function with an Eloquent relationship using anonymous classes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, php-7

I'm trying to test a trait which is used in a few Eloquent models in my application. The testing approach I'm taking is making an anonymous class in my test class and testing that the trait method invoked on the anonymous class returns the correct results. I'm running into issues due to relationships being called in the trait method with which the anonymous class approach seems to be struggling.

I've created an anonymous class in my test class which extends the Eloquent model and uses my trait I'm trying to test. I've also specified the relationship in the anon class which is then used in the trait method I'm trying to test. However, since the relationship is many to many, when I try and call the relationship in the test, Eloquent is looking in a join table ai2nx3xla_emails (ai2nx3xla being the hidden name of the anon class) which of course doesn't exist in my database.

Relevant parts of the test class

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->testClass = new class extends Model {
        use Contactable;

        public function emails()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email')->withPivot('default');
        }
    };
}

/** @test */
public function it_can_return_the_default_email_for_a_model()
{
    $email = factory(\App\Email::class)->make();
    $this->testClass->setRelation('emails', $email);
    $this->assertEquals($email->id, $this->testClass->defaultEmail());
}
```

Relevant parts of the trait (boiled down for simplicity)

```
abstract public function emails();

/**
 * Return the default email if exists
 *
 */
public function email()
{
    $email = $this->emails()->wherePivot('default', true)->first() ?? $this->emails()->first();
    return $email;
}
```

I'm expecting the test to pass but I'm actually getting this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that >corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use >near '.`php0x10c63a39e_id` as `pivot_contactable_test.php0x10c63a39e_
>   id`, `contactable' at line 1

My question would be, is there a way I can make this work in the current setup? Or should I approach this test in a different way? eg. testing a real model which uses the trait? Reluctant to do that though since if I remove the trait from that model the tests will fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you'd need to test it on a real model that uses the trait. Sure, if you remove the trait, the tests will fail and I think that's a good thing, right? You'd be able to spot breaking changes quickly and refactor your code.

Comment: @Mozammil yes that's a good point, but then should I be testing the trait functions in each model which uses the trait? or just test one and assume the rest are good?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your trait does and can't really comment on how it should be tested..

Comment: well in this example (contrived for simplicity) the trait method returns the default email for a user if it exists, otherwise just returns the first email from the database. i'd like to test that the trait function `email()` does just that

Comment: I would probably test it in all the models that it is used in to be honest. I am, personally, quite defensive. Also, you never know if other developers in your team have accidentally defined an implementation of `email()` that overrides your trait method, for example.

Comment: ah yes i didn't think about that overriding issue. feels like a more robust approach doing this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because queries done by Laravel are based on the classname (classnametolower_id) to get the foreign key but you can provide the table name as well i think this will resolve your problem :

```
new class extends Model {
        use Contactable;

        protected $table = 'yourtable';

        public function emails()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email')->withPivot('default');
        }
    };
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. that makes sense but then I'd have to specify a real table name i have in my database wouldn't I? And if I was doing that I may as well test the trait method using the real model which uses the trait?

Comment: Yes for sure, you can use your method provided in your trait in this anonymous class ! ;)

Comment: so let's say the model `User` has a many to many relationship with `Email` and the `User` class uses the trait. would you recommend setting `protected $table = 'users';` in the anonymous class? if that's the case then surely I should just test the `email()` method in my `User` test suite?

Comment: Yeah but to improve it, you can provide all the keys in your `belongsToMany` method : `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email', 'pivot_table', 'user_id', 'email_id');`